# MySQL group_concat of distinct value

Tags: mysql

In mysql, consider the case

```
       group_concat(distinct emailid, email)
```

displays following result:

```
      22praveep@gmail,53praveep@gamil,24kk@gmail.com
```

I need only emails of distinct id in result how to get it. i need query inside group_concat as many join and select query has been used in my mysql query.

Comment: It can't be done "*inside group_concat*".  You'd have to join the set of distinct `emailid` values back to a set of `email` values to obtain your desired results.  Perhaps your overall query can be simplified?

Comment: if I understood you correctly `group_concat(distinct  email)` should work. please try it

Comment: @zahiro distinct email provides result as distinct of email values, i can have same email value for different id. i need those emails but not repeatedly as i have group by in my query , emails are repeated.

Comment: or is there any thing like that which makes empty  of emptyid

Comment: what should be your desired output?